# Django Rest Framework : string return b'' string

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and I create few API calls.

API calls return primarily data from model objects. All other API work normally but one parameter in JSON in one API return b'' string instead of a normal string.

I can't found a difference between others and this one. What could be the problem?

```
class ApiVisit(APIView):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @logging__time
    def get(self, request, pk, call_type):
        r = {}
        user = self.request.user
        ...
        notes = ....

        r['notes'] = notes

        return  Response(r)
```

From Postman I get

[image]

Comment: A `b` string is binary string, it usually means you did a `str(..)` or `repr(..)` on something that is not a string. Likely your `notes` is the response of a request?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

For all that have the same problem: the problem was not in fetching note properties, but in saving it.

I have:

```
call.notes = request.body
```

which is a binary string. I change it to:

```
call.notes = request.body.decode("utf-8")
```